# How to update value of CountJS with react and firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I m using Firebase , Count js in my web application.
Here is my code.

```
import firebase from 'firebase';
import CountUp from 'react-countup';
const config = { ... }
class Stracture extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        if (!firebase.apps.length) {
        firebase.initializeApp(config);
    }
    this.state = { balance: 0 };
}
componentDidMount() {
    firebase.database().ref('user1').child('balance').on('value', snap => {
        this.setState({ balance: snap.val()})
    });
}
render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    return (
        <CountUp className={classes.typo2} decimals={2} duration={1.5} end={this.state.balance} prefix="Balance: " suffix=" $" />
    )
};
```

My codes works fine. But now i want to use update function to update the value from recent value. Because, when Firebase data are changing this animation starts from 0..

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to write an update function then add an onClick handler to the `CountUp` component that point to the new function.

```
<CountUp onClick={() => this.handleUpdate()} className={classes.typo2} decimals={2} duration={1.5} end={this.state.balance} prefix="Balance: " suffix=" $"  />
```

Then create the `handleUpdate` function in the class and make it increment the balance value in firebase.

```
class Stracture extends React.Component {

  constructor() {...}

  componentDidMount() {...}

  handleUpdate = () => firebase.database().ref('user1').update({balance: this.state.balance + 1})

  render() {...}

}
```

More on [how updates work here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#update_specific_fields).

You don't need to update state since you already have a real-time listener, so once you update the value in firebase the change will automatically propagate to your app.

If you want to pass in a value rather then increment by one then pass that value into the onClick handler and accept it as a parameter to the handleUpdate function.

Two other things you should probably keep in mind include error handling the update function, so you could wrap it in a try/catch block and [detaching the real-time listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#detach_listeners) in componentWillUnmount.